Expresso Store version 4 or 5 needed
I know that further work on Expresso Store module has been suspended in 2020, but I need a newer version. I have version 3.0 which I need to upgrade now. On the official website, I see that there were versions 4 and 5 of Store, but it does not offer me the option to download. I sent a ticket a week ago - no response. Does anyone have the .zip with Expresso Store 4 or version 5 ??
Thanks

I may have something on an external disk. Will have to look for it.
Contact me over at the EE Slack channel
